# Diccionarios en Python vs Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, python, object, diccionarios

Tengo una duda entre si los `Dict` en Python y los `Object` en Javascript son el mismo concepto y ya que considero que si hacen lo mismo.

Ejemplo en Python

```
nombres = {}
nombres['Yoel'] = 1
nombres['Manolito'] = 2
nombres['Pepe'] = 3
```

Ejemplo en Javascript

```
var nombres = new Object();
nombres['Yoel'] = 1
nombres['Manolito'] = 2
nombres['Pepe'] = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

El concepto es similar pero no son lo mismo. Los objetos de Javascript son como un diccionario o mapa pero tienen ciertas limitaciones. De hecho, en las últimas versiones del estándar Javascript hay una nueva clase Map para resolver estas limitaciones. De la página de MDN sobre la clase [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Map#Objetos_y_mapas_comparados):

> Los Objetos son similares a los Mapas en cuanto a que ambos le
>   permiten establecer claves a valores, recuperar dichos valores,
>   eliminar claves, y detectar si existe algo almacenado en una clave
>   determinada. Por esto, los Objetos han sido usados históricamente como
>   Mapas historically; no obstante, hay diferencias importantes entre 
>   Objetos y Mapas que hacen mejor usar un  Mapa.
>
> - Un Objeto tiene un prototipo, de modo que hay claves por defecto en el mapa. No obstante, esto puede ser sorteado usando map =
>     Object.create(null).
> - Las claves de un Objeto son Strings, mientras que pueden ser valores de cualquier tipo para un Mapa.
> - Puede obtenerse fácilmente el tamaño de un Mapa  mientras que debe mantenerse manualmente el trazado del tamaño de un Objeto.

Esta clase Map si que viene a ser el mismo concepto que los [Dict de Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)